# jquery script don't work inside spring project

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

In my spring project, I added four *.js files with jquery event handler for perform several activities on my project. One of them is this script, placed inside the file form_validation.js:

**jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/f8U4c/79/

**code**

```
$('.valida').each(function(){

    $(this).on('focus', function(e){
        regex = $(this).attr('pattern');

        counter = 0;
        tam = size_of(regex);
        str = generate_string(regex, tam);

        $(this).val(str);
    });

    $(this).on('keypress', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var tecla = e.which;
        var tecla2;

        if(tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57)
            tecla2 = tecla - 48;
        else
            tecla2 = String.fromCharCode(tecla);

        result = $("<div>");
        result.append( "tecla = "+tecla+"<br>" );

        var t = type_of(regex, counter);

        if(counter < tam) {
            if(t != 'number' && t != 'string') {
                str = replaceAt(str, counter, t);
                counter++;
            }

            t = type_of(regex, counter);

            if(typeof tecla2 == t) {
                result.append( "tecla2 = "+tecla2+"<br>" );
                str = replaceAt(str, counter, tecla2);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        result.append( "counter = "+counter+"<br>" );
        $("#result").empty().append(result);

        $(this).val(str);
    });

});
```

which it's the only one that doesn't work when I run my application and open a page with a field with the class 'valida'. In my project, I change the code for that:

```
$(document).find('.valida').each(function(e){
    $(this).on('focus', '.valida', function(e){
        regex = $(this).attr('pattern');

        counter = 0;
        tam = size_of(regex);
        str = generate_string(regex, tam);

        $(this).val(str);
    });

    $(this).on('keypress', '.valida', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var tecla = e.which;
        var tecla2;

        if(tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57)
            tecla2 = tecla - 48;
        else
            tecla2 = String.fromCharCode(tecla);

        var t = type_of(regex, counter);

        if(counter < tam) {
            if(t != 'number' && t != 'string') {
                str = replaceAt(str, counter, t);
                counter++;
            }

            t = type_of(regex, counter);

            if(typeof tecla2 == t) {
                str = replaceAt(str, counter, tecla2);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        $(this).val(str);
    });
});
```

Anyone knows why this code don't work in my project?

ps.: the direct link to this file inside my project tree is here:

https://github.com/klebermo/lojavirtual/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/jsp/resources/extras/js

**UPDATE**

What I try so far, besides what was presented above, but still couldn't make this work:

1) Use of $(document).on() for both function, outside any wrapper

2) Use of $(document).on() inside $(document).find('.valida').each()

3) Use of $(document).on() inside $(document).ready()

I really can't figure out what's happening here.

**UPDATE 2**

I need add one more script with issues. The code below is workin fine, except the highlighted part:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.form', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $( this ),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

    if($("select.lista").length) {
        jQuery('select.lista').find('option.item').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        });
    }

    var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        $("#"+data).css("display", "block");

        if($("#pergunta").is(":visible"))
            $("#pergunta").css("display", "none");

        $(".form").each (function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    });
});
```

**
    if($("select.lista").length) {
        jQuery('select.lista').find('option.item').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        });
    }
**

I need that piece of code to allow me send the content of `<select>` to server when the form is submitted.

Comment: are you using a `ready` handler to wrap code?

Comment: No, neither this and neither the other scripts; I am using for all of them `$(document).on('event', 'element', function(e){`. Only with this file no action happens when I open the jsp pages.

Comment: wrap in a ready handler so the elements exist when code runs. Will work in fiddle because they wrap it for you

Comment: Like I said, this script it's the only one which doesn't work. the problem with the use of the wrapper `ready()`it's the jquery code is placed in a separated file, included in the file dashboard.jsp, where all the other jsp files are included when they are requested.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, or why you can't wrap the code

Comment: see the link in the final of the question.

Comment: that's a directory of files...what would that tell me? you can call `ready` numerous times

Comment: Where is the spring and/or spring mvc related issue?

Comment: the js files are included in jsp files inside a spring project. When I try execute them outside the project, the scripts work fine, but inside the project, they don't (when I say they, I mean only the script form_validation.js mentioned above).